# How does this APL golden ratio code work?

Tags: apl

This is code for the golden ratio in Dyalog APL:

```
1+∘÷⍣=1
```

I don't get it. "1 plus compose rec repeat equals 1" does not make any sense.

Answer (score 7):

The operands of `⍣` are `+∘÷` (the left) and `=` (the right). Its arguments are both `1`.

`⍣` with a function right operand is "until", which repeats the left operand until the right operand, called with the last two results, gives `1`. So, here `⍣=` is "repeat until equal" - find the fixed point.

`⍣` calls its left operand with the same left argument as its left argument (so always `1`), but cycles the right one with the new results.
So, `+∘÷` is called dyadically, which is the same as the dfn `{⍺ + ÷⍵}`. `⍺` here is always the same 1 because that's the left argument of `⍣`.

Altogether, this code does `1 + ÷last` until the last result and this one are equal. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6phYUPGqbYGjOZaigof2oY8bh7Y96FxtqKhiiCBihCxijC5igC5himGGqacilrqenpw4UVoAL2yoA1amDxKof9e7SBoltrQWJG3JVGypoKyAJAAA)

Dyalog APLs `]box on -trains=tree`:

```
  ⍣ 
 ┌┴┐
 ∘ =
┌┴┐ 
+ ÷
```

Comment: So, how do I do what you just did to show me the structure? I copied "]box on -trains=tree" in there, and it kept saying "Usage: ]box on | off". I use TryAPL

Comment: @Ikura tryAPL seems to not have the options for `]box`, so just `]box on` is enough for it to work

Answer (score 4):

#### +∘÷

The reciprocal is applied monadically to the right operand, and the result is added to the left operand. `10+∘÷4 → 10.25` and `1+∘÷1 → 2`.

#### ⍣number

When we repeat a dyadic function, the right operand is "updated" but the left operand stays the same. `1+∘÷⍣2⊢1 → 1+∘÷2 → 1.5`

#### ⍣function

Repeat again and again, as long as (current result) ***f*** (previous result) is false. This way, `⍣=` repeats until convergence, as if "∞ times".

Comment: Aha! Great job! I know this method where you reciprocate and increment!

Answer (score 1):

Now I get it, thanks to you! Lemme summarize!
x+∘÷y is a composed function. First, you calculate 1/y, then, it is composed with addition, and x is added. Now, here is where our sour-candy-loving (he puckers all the time) repeat guy comes in! A test: 1 (+⍣10) 1. He starts at 1, and adds 1, and does this again to the result, until he does it ten times. If the 10 becomes an =, he will stop when the previous result is equal to the current result! x (f⍣u) y, in this case, would have x, f, u and y, be 1, +∘÷, = and 1. This "reciprocal + 1" method is a classic method, I think.